# Does Selenium- Jenkins Integration needs TestNG or JUnit Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, testng, jenkins-cli

Should we need TestNG or Junit framework to integrate Selenium with Jenkins. I have project which is build without TestNG or JUnit can i integrate it with Jenkins.

Comment: TestNG and JUnit are testing frameworks, they have nothing to do with Jenkins.

Comment: Yeah here we are using Jenkins for Testing Purpose only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNG and JUnit on simple terms can be visualised as "java code execution" mechanisms with support to do validations.
So instead of you having only one `main()` method that would be the single point of entry for execution of your selenium code, TestNG/JUnit takes up that role and lets you run multiple java classes via themselves.

Jenkins is an orchestrator tool that lets you build, test, deploy as per your wish.

The test phase can be skipped by not using TestNG and JUnit, and you resorting to executing your selenium based tests via a `main()` method which takes care of doing all validations as well (assertions in the JUnit/TestNG world)

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `JUnit` and `TestNG` frameworks as Jenkins supports both.

Steps in details for `TestNG` integration with `Jenkins`.

**Step 1:** Create <kbd>Free Style project</kbd> in Jenkins and fill the details and <kbd>Save</kbd> the project.

**Step 2:** click on <kbd>Configure</kbd>

**Step 3:** In the <kbd>Build</kbd> section of <kbd>Configure</kbd>:

```
java -cp J:\taf\testng\*;J:\taf\workspace\TestNGExamples\bin;J:\automation\* org.testng.TestNG J:\taf\workspace\TestNGExamples\testng1.xml
```

Note: you have to change the paths as per your system.

In `-cp` argument, we must provide `testng.jar`, `project location` and ``selenium jars`locations/paths.`
org.testng.TestNG`- TestNG Main Class.
and`location to the XML of testng configuration`

---

Download and install the `testng-plugin` for jenkins from [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin) and restart Jenkins in order to take effect.

**Step 4:** In the `Post-build Actions` section,

1. Select <kbd>Publish TestNG Results</kbd> from <kbd>Add post-build action</kbd> dropdown.
2. provide the path where to look for TestNG results (.xml file containing results).
3. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>Save</kbd> buttons.

Screenshot for reference:

[image]